# What is the etymology of the word しょーむない?

Tags: words, kansai-ben

> しょーむない更新失礼しました(T^T)
>   Sorry for the boring update

From my understanding, しょーむない means something along the lines of くだらない and つまらない. Where does it originate from and is it specific to a certain dialect?

Comment: I think it's a typo of しょーもない. Are you sure with the source?

Comment: she wrote it twice but she is 20 and from osaka if that is any help. I'll ask her.

Comment: maybe it is just a slang spelling of しょうがない?

Comment: i got this answer but no link yet so maybe it is something different
しょーむないを調べてみると
英語で表すのはrubbish foolish nonsenceって表すらしい！！

Comment: Haha we Kansai residents sometimes pronouce しょ～もない (=くだらない、ばかばかしい) like しょ～むな～ just to sound funny.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a couple of similar expressions with overlapping meanings here, so I'll elaborate on @sawa's answer to add some color.

しょーむない is probably a cute slangy way to say しょうもない, which is a common contraction of しようもない, which means "silly" or "useless". This is mainly used in western dialects, and the standard would be しようがない (often contracted to しょうがない) or くだらない.

しようがない, however, also has the meaning "there's nothing we (you, I etc) can do about it", similar to しかたがない. In western dialects, this might be expressed as しゃーない, and I'm actually not sure which one of the above this is a contraction of.

There is also an expression どうしようもない (どうしようもない) which does *not* have a particularly dialectal feel to it, and can mean both "silly"/"useless" or "there's nothing we can do about it".

Finally, there is no どうしようがない, since the どう requires the も, but どうにもしようがない is common as well.

Answer (score 2):

`しょうもない` is a contracted form of `しようもない` "there is no way to be done," "there is nothing we can do about it." `し` is "do", `よう` is "manner." `しよう` is "manner in which to do." It is mainly used in Kansai dialects. In Tokyo area, `しょうがない` is used.

Comment: しょうもない and しょうがない are both used in Kansai and not interchangeable. Their usages are totally different. See dainichi's answer.